# Ruby 2.3.1 on Ubuntu 18.04: [BUG] Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby, gcc, rake

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
rbenv 1.0.0
Bundler version 1.16.2
rake, version 10.5.0
```

Using `bundle exec rake db:drop` causes:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:drop
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0050 p:---- s:0189 e:000188 CFUNC  :initialize
c:0049 p:---- s:0187 e:000186 CFUNC  :new
c:0048 p:0129 s:0184 E:000e90 CLASS  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:67
c:0047 p:0011 s:0182 e:000181 CLASS  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:18
c:0046 p:0011 s:0180 e:000179 CLASS  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:17
c:0045 p:0027 s:0178 e:000177 TOP    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:16 [FINISH]
c:0044 p:---- s:0176 e:000175 CFUNC  :require
c:0043 p:0071 s:0172 e:000171 TOP    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl.rb:21 [FINISH]
c:0042 p:---- s:0170 e:000169 CFUNC  :require
c:0041 p:0017 s:0166 e:000165 TOP    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0040 p:---- s:0164 e:000163 CFUNC  :require
c:0039 p:0023 s:0160 e:000159 TOP    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/rest-client.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0038 p:---- s:0158 e:000157 CFUNC  :require
c:0037 p:0042 s:0154 e:000153 BLOCK  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81 [FINISH]
c:0036 p:---- s:0150 e:000149 CFUNC  :each
c:0035 p:0062 s:0147 e:000146 BLOCK  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0034 p:---- s:0141 e:000140 CFUNC  :each
c:0033 p:0038 s:0138 e:000137 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65
c:0032 p:0019 s:0134 e:000133 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114
c:0031 p:0131 s:0130 e:000129 TOP    ~/Projects/projectname/mod_finance/config/boot.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0030 p:---- s:0128 e:000127 CFUNC  :require
c:0029 p:0044 s:0124 e:000123 TOP    ~/Projects/projectname/mod_finance/Rakefile:12 [FINISH]
c:0028 p:---- s:0122 e:000121 CFUNC  :load
c:0027 p:0010 s:0118 e:000117 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28
c:0026 p:0199 s:0114 e:000113 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:689
c:0025 p:0008 s:0109 e:000108 BLOCK  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94
c:0024 p:0006 s:0107 e:000106 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176
c:0023 p:0009 s:0103 e:000102 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93
c:0022 p:0015 s:0100 e:000099 BLOCK  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77
c:0021 p:0006 s:0098 e:000097 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176
c:0020 p:0009 s:0094 e:000093 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75
c:0019 p:0045 s:0091 e:000090 TOP    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33 [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0089 e:000088 CFUNC  :load
c:0017 p:0147 s:0085 e:000084 TOP    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:23 [FINISH]
c:0016 p:---- s:0081 e:000080 CFUNC  :load
c:0015 p:0148 s:0077 e:000076 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74
c:0014 p:0089 s:0069 e:000068 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28
c:0013 p:0032 s:0065 e:000064 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424
c:0012 p:0078 s:0061 e:000060 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27
c:0011 p:0058 s:0054 e:000053 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126
c:0010 p:0305 s:0048 e:000047 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387
c:0009 p:0012 s:0036 e:000035 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27
c:0008 p:0070 s:0032 e:000031 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466
c:0007 p:0012 s:0026 e:000025 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18
c:0006 p:0090 s:0021 e:000020 BLOCK  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/exe/bundle:30
c:0005 p:0006 s:0016 e:000015 METHOD ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124
c:0004 p:0056 s:0012 E:000750 TOP    ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/exe/bundle:22 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0010 e:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0147 s:0006 E:0007a0 EVAL   ~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000f20 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
~/Projects/projectname/mod_finance/Rakefile:12:in `<top (required)>'
~/Projects/projectname/mod_finance/Rakefile:12:in `require'
~/Projects/projectname/mod_finance/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/rest-client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/rest-client.rb:2:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient.rb:2:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl.rb:21:in `require'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:17:in `<module:OpenSSL>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:18:in `<module:SSL>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:67:in `<class:SSLContext>'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:67:in `new'
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl/ssl.rb:67:in `initialize'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007fb1f24c4604 RBP: 0x000055ec996d73c0 RSP: 0x00007ffe6120db78
 RAX: 0x0000000000000000 RBX: 0x0000000000000018 RCX: 0x00007fb1ed4830f8
 RDX: 0x0000000000000008 RDI: 0x00007ffe6120d690 RSI: 0x0000000000000000
  R8: 0x00007fb1ed263f40  R9: 0x0000000000000000 R10: 0x000000000000003f
 R11: 0x00007fb1f24d3470 R12: 0x0000000000000000 R13: 0x0000000000000008
 R14: 0x000055ec9993ccc8 R15: 0x000055ec9994ab20 EFL: 0x0000000000010206

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_vm_bugreport+0x535) [0x55ec97169e75] vm_dump.c:688
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_bug_context+0xd1) [0x55ec97146cb1] error.c:435
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(sigsegv+0x3e) [0x55ec970405ae] signal.c:890
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 [0x7fb1f5ccb890]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_sk_set+0x14) [0x7fb1f24c4604]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1(CRYPTO_set_ex_data+0x8f) [0x7fb1f246d3cf]
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so(ossl_x509store_initialize+0x5d) [0x7fb1ed263f9d] ossl_x509store.c:133
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call0_body.constprop.119+0x280) [0x55ec970cc950] vm_eval.c:131
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_call0+0xc7) [0x55ec970ccf27] vm_eval.c:61
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_class_new_instance+0x21) [0x55ec96fe2381] object.c:1856
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_require_internal+0x630) [0x55ec96f80440] load.c:998
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_require+0x13) [0x55ec96f806b3] load.c:1043
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_require_internal+0x630) [0x55ec96f80440] load.c:998
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_require+0x13) [0x55ec96f806b3] load.c:1043
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_require_internal+0x630) [0x55ec96f80440] load.c:998
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_require+0x13) [0x55ec96f806b3] load.c:1043
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_require_internal+0x630) [0x55ec96f80440] load.c:998
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_require+0x13) [0x55ec96f806b3] load.c:1043
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(invoke_block_from_c_0+0x2be) [0x55ec970cab7e] vm.c:921
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x5c) [0x55ec970d1a6c] vm.c:988
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x3d) [0x55ec970f2ded] array.c:1815
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x124b) [0x55ec970c53bb] insns.def:964
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(invoke_block_from_c_0+0x2be) [0x55ec970cab7e] vm.c:921
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x5c) [0x55ec970d1a6c] vm.c:988
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x3d) [0x55ec970f2ded] array.c:1815
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x124b) [0x55ec970c53bb] insns.def:964
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_require_internal+0x630) [0x55ec96f80440] load.c:998
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_require+0x13) [0x55ec96f806b3] load.c:1043
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_load+0x82) [0x55ec96f7efb2] load.c:649
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_load+0x82) [0x55ec96f7efb2] load.c:649
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_load+0x82) [0x55ec96f7efb2] load.c:649
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_load_internal0+0xb9) [0x55ec96f7e929] load.c:619
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(rb_f_load+0x82) [0x55ec96f7efb2] load.c:649
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_cfunc+0xf0) [0x55ec970be450] vm_insnhelper.c:1638
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method_each_type+0xb1) [0x55ec970cb001] vm_insnhelper.c:2022
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_call_method+0xe3) [0x55ec970cb593] vm_insnhelper.c:2172
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec_core+0x1318) [0x55ec970c5488] insns.def:995
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(vm_exec+0x86) [0x55ec970c9ed6] vm.c:1650
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(ruby_exec_internal+0xba) [0x55ec96f78bca] eval.c:245
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(ruby_run_node+0x2f) [0x55ec96f7c90f] eval.c:310
~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby(main+0x4b) [0x55ec96f787fb] parse.y:7826
```

I've tried many different solutions like installing **libssl1.0-dev** instead of **libssl-dev**, installing ruby with gcc-5 or gcc-6 `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5 rbenv install 2.3.1`, etc. and still having this issue.

One thing that helped is

```
$ CC=/usr/bin/gcc-5 bundle exec rake db:drop
Dropped database 'development_tpay_finance'
Dropped database 'test_tpay_finance'
```

I think the reason is gcc, but how to force ruby to use specific version of gcc?
Maybe you know any other solutions for this case?

Comment: Hi! To get answers it's always helpful to start a question with a description of what you're trying to do. Good luck!

Comment: Similar bug reported under 2.3.1 [#13310](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13310) suggested solution was [upgrade to 2.3.3 or newer](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13310#note-2)

Comment: @engineersmnky Unfortunately i cannot update to 2.3.3 because entire project uses version 2.3.1.

Comment: Although I have not seen the code base the teeny version jump should not really impact anything. I would branch and upgrade and then run the specs to make sure but it is worth a shot over trying to fix this very internal issue